# Fitting Image at the top of the scaffold evenly

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to fit a this image -[(Its a PNG image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPBd8.jpg) at the top of the scaffold

I am somewhat expecting this

[image: Needed output]

And below is my output

[image: My Output]

I used Sliver App bar but still I am not able to get the desired output, so I have used some different approach here

And here is the code for that -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class home extends StatefulWidget {
  const home({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _homeState createState() => _homeState();
}

class _homeState extends State<home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 75.0, left: 30.0, right: 30.0, bottom: 30.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Control',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 40.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Panel',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 40.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 150,),
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 25.0,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(35.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(35.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Is there any way to add that image ?

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous answer wasn't exactly what you probably wanted, so here's a better example of how to accomplish what you want!

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 75.0, left: 30.0, right: 30.0, bottom: 30.0
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: const <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Control',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 40.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'Panel',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 40.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 150,),
          const CircleAvatar(radius: 25.0,)
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Positioned.fill(
      left: -100, // adjust to your choice
      right: -100, // adjust to your choice
      child: Image.network(
        "https://i.imgur.com/dJFih13.png",
        fit: BoxFit.cover
      ),
    )
  ],
),
```

Comment: Thanx, it worked!! :)